# Print SAPUI5 VizFrame Bullet chart vertically

Tags: java, html, css, charts, sapui5

Hi I have a question about Viz charts in UI5. I´m searching for a way to rotate the Viz Bullet chart while printing in a new window. 
If I open it in a new window `window.open();` the CSS for the chart rotation is lost. Is there a command to rotate it vertical in the new window? Here's an example for Viz Bullet chart

[SAP Bullet Viz Sample &](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.viz.sample.Bullet/preview) 
[Printing Example](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2014/04/24/preview-print-of-sapui5-viz-charts)

Is there a way to use something like this `@media print { @page {size: landscape}}`
but only on the chart and not the whole page?